# Plane intersection with four sphere, with constraints

Tags: geometry, vectors

[image]I have a complicated problem, I need to find the equation of plane which intersects with four known spheres with equal radius. I believe we would have infinite solutions with these conditions, but when I look to equations of plane $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$

If it is solved with four sphere equations:

$$\begin{cases}(x_1-x_o1)^2+(y_1-y_o1)^2+(z_1-z_o1)^2=R^2 \\ \cdots\\(x_4-x_o4)^2+(y_4-y_o4)^2+(z_4-z_o4)^2=R^2 \end{cases}$$

we could solve for $A, B, C, D$ to get unique solution which confuses me.

My real problem is I have a planar rectangle with known dimensions, its four corners will be on the four spheres, the middle point of the top rectangle’s line would have the coordinates $(x_5,0,z_5)$ and would interest with another circle in the $xz$-plane. 
$$\begin{cases}(x_5-x_o5)^2+(z_5-z_o5)^2=R^2 \end{cases}$$

I need to find the four corners coordinates based on those constraints but I do not know where to start, help would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question: if you take $Ax + By + Cz + D = 0$ and plug it into the four sphere equations, you'll be looking for values of $A,B,C, D$ that solve the circle equations...for a particular $(x, y, z)$! That means you'll be looking for a plane that contains a single point on all four spheres...and you're not likely to find one. That's no surprise: If your four spheres were small ones around the vertices of a regular tetrahedron, then there's no plane that even intersects them in *different* points, let alone the *same* point.

As for your "real problem", can you perhaps state it a little more clearly? I understand that you have a planar rectangle.

1. Is it in the $xz$ plane? the $xy$ plane? or just some unknown plane?
2. What do you mean by "the top rectangle"? I though you had just one rectangle!
3. Everything after "would have coordinates" makes no sense to me. Perhaps you can split this into several sentences that are clearer. Or maybe you can draw something, take a photo, and upload that photo to explain what you mean.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response, sorry for the unclear part,they are actually spheres not circles

Comment: Spheres not circles actually.the plane(rectangle) is in 3d space and should be intersecting with those four spheres wherever they move, while keeping the constraints of the rectangle(one), like distance of corners points relative to each others while being on spheres surface, rectangle's lines being perpendicular to each others.there is an additional constraint, which is the middle point of rectangle's top edge has to intersect with another planar circle in the xz plane, this is why that point would have coordinates of x_5,0,z_5, I will try to make 3d drawing of the problem and post it,thanks

Comment: I changed "circle" to "sphere", but the same algebraic point applies. As for the problem you seem to be describing in your second comment, for arbitrarily-moving spheres, it won't have a solution in general (as the spheres might move to become small spheres about the corners of a tetrahedron, or might move so that no points of two spheres are closer than 2 miles, while your rectangle is only 7 inches on a side).

Comment: any idea how to add images to this post, sorry, it is my first experience here

Comment: When you're typing your question (or answer), there's a list of icons above the box you type in; they let you change text to bold, italic, add hyperlinks, etc. One of these is a little "image" icon, and if you click it, it'll let you upload an image from your computer (I believe).

Comment: Hope it look clear now, it is a valid problem since I can draw it in Solidworks and impose all those constraints and get valid and unique solutions for position and orientation of the rectangle, but I need to make a close form solution of this problem mathematically.